# Error importing opencv, unable to import VideoCapturePlayer

Tags: python, opencv, module

I am trying to work with OpenCV in Python 2.7, however when I simply import cv2, I am getting this error:

```
>>> import cv2 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
  File "cv2.py", line 9, in <module> 
    from VideoCapturePlayer import * 
ImportError: No module named VideoCapturePlayer
```

I figured that VideoCapturePlayer may be in pygame or pycam, but when I import both, no problems arise.
I have searched my folders and the web for VideoCapturePlayer. My folders do not contain it, and the internet provided a .py file, but I do not know where I should put it. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I guess I should include that I am on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: How did you install OpenCV?

Comment: I used the windows installer, it found the registry entry for python2.7 fine. Also, thank you for editing.

Comment: Where did you obtain the Windows installer?

Comment: Found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=dlp

Comment: Ah. I'll write you up an answer that should get you working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is for downloading the entire OpenCV project, including all the libraries and bindings for C++, Java, etc. etc. For the Python bindings, it's much easier to visit my favorite module site on the Internet, Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. Find the [OpenCV section](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv), pick AMD64 or Win32, pick py2.7 or py2.6, and wait a bit for the self-extracting archive to download. Run it, hit OK for all the prompts, and you should be all set. Fire up IDLE or run `python` from the command line, and running `import cv2` should give you no response at all - indicating that everything got set up just fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Try opening `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` and deleting any files that start with `cv` or `cv2`, then reinstalling Gohlke's package. Just for fun, you might also want to try downloading `numpy` from the same place. I know it's required to build OpenCV, not sure if it is to run it...

Comment: @user3341951 glad I could be of assistance. If my answer helped solve your issue, please indicate it by clicking the check mark next to it. This will mark the question as resolved, and we'll both get reputation points for it. Please see [What does it mean if an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more info. Thanks!